# Speeding up my geopy function

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, user-defined-functions, geopy

I have a set of lat-long coordinates in a column of a df. The format is lat, long. The idea is to determine the zipcode (postal code) and add a column with that number to the df.

Here is the column

```
10        40.7145,-73.9425
10000     40.7947,-73.9667
100004    40.7388,-74.0018
100007    40.7539,-73.9677
100013    40.8241,-73.9493
```

I created this function using geopy to get the information I want:

```
>>>def zipcode (coords):# 
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.reverse(coords)
    zip=location.raw['address']['postcode']
    return zip
```

It works fine in a small subset of the data frame, but when I try it in the larger dataset, it stalls.

Was wondering if someone can give me a more efficient way to do this.